# Specific Time Range Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am Trying to select the values of rows inserted between a range of time;

i.e Between 8am Today and 8am the previous day.

This is to Run as a cron job everyday to check the qty inserted between that time period and insert data in another table.

Below is the table;

[image: order table]

Comment: Do you just need the SQL statement to get the data between the specific range?

Comment: Yes, I only need the SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple way is to convert the `date_time` to a date value -- after subtracting 8 hours:

```
where date(from_unixtime(date_time - 8 * 60 * 60)) = curdate() - interval 1 day
```

A more efficient way is to do this entirely in the realm of Unix times:

```
where date_time < unix_timestamp(curdate() + interval 8 hour) and
      date_time >= unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 16 hour)
```

Comment: So will this pick data  for the range of 24hrs?

Comment: @KelvinMuli . . . 24 hours is one day, so yes.  The day goes from 8:00 am yesterday to 8:00 am today.